# Formula to find if a set of values in excel column is out of range

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, formula

[image]

There are certain values in a column in excel, like

108
108.7
2657
35678
4563
108.8
108.9
108.95

How in excel formula or python can we mark the cells with number out of range like in the above case 2657,35678 and 4563?
Request inputs on it

This is the formula i am using:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Final!A3),"Y",IF(ISNUMBER(Final!$A2:Final!$A4),IF(OR(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Final!A2)),NOT(ISBLANK(Final!A4)),ISNUMBER(Final!A2:Final!A4),Final!A3>Final!A2,Final!A3>Final!A4,Final!A3>Final!A5),AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Final!A2)),NOT(ISBLANK(Final!A4)),NOT(ISBLANK(Final!A5)),ISNUMBER(Final!A2:Final!A4),Final!A3<Final!A2,Final!A3>Final!A4,Final!A3<Final!A5),AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Final!A2)),NOT(ISBLANK(Final!A4)),ISNUMBER(Final!A2:Final!A4),Final!A3<Final!A2,Final!A3<Final!A1,Final!A3<Final!A4),AND(ISBLANK(Final!A2),NOT(ISBLANK(Final!A4)),ISNUMBER(Final!A2:Final!A4),Final!A3>Final!A2,Final!A3<Final!A4,Final!A3<Final!A1)),"Y","."),IF(OR(AND(Final!A3>Final!A2,Final!A3>Final!A4),AND(Final!A3<Final!A2,Final!A3<Final!A4)),IF(AND(Final!$A3=Final!$A2,Final!$A3=Final!$A4),IF(Final!A3=MAX((Final!$A$2:Final!$A$100000=Final!$A2),Final!A2:INDEX(Final!A2:Final!A100000,SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT(Final!$A3,Final!$A2:Final!$A$100000)))),".","Y"),"."),".")))
```

The spikes need to be marked in a second sheet of Excel, if at all there is a high or low in the values in the excel.But if continous values are high or low, its not detecting the values.

I am also marking blank cells if any in between in the columns as 'Y' indicating a high or low in the values

The values in a column which fall out of range. Like if there is 1, 2,3, 6000,8000, 9000,4,5,6 here 6000, 8000 and 9000 are clearly out of range and do not fall between 1 and 6. I am able to identify if a single value in a column is out of range. But if continous values are out of range not able to identify it with excel formula.

Expected output in the second sheet of Excel with the formula applied:

[image]

Comment: What is the range, where do you want the output stored? Should the cells be renamed if OOR, should a new column be defined stating OOR cells, should the cells color be changed? You will need to provide more information, and code which you have tried to resolve the issue with for more assistance to be provided.

Comment: Please let me know if a similar thing can be done using Python. i have put the code in the below answer section

Comment: If its python those out of range cells need to be marked as NaN

Comment: How do you define the numeric range? I mean, how do you define that the range is 108-108,99? Would be 109 out of range? The number that defines each range is always the first one? Your question needs more focus, indeed.

Comment: There is an excel sheet which has certain data all the numbers are in a ascending or descending form, but few numbers in the column appear to be out of the range of values as i have given above if the range starts at 108 and ends at 109.9 in a column (these again vary in different set of excel data)then in between numbers come as 2168 or 0 either of the values do not fall in the range of numbers in that excel column.So need to identify the numbers which are out of range in that column.

Comment: The values in a column which fall out of range. Like if there is 1, 2,3, 6000,8000, 9000,4,5,6 here 6000, 8000 and 9000 are clearly out of range and do not fall between 1 and 6. I  am able to identify if a single value in a column is out of range. But if continous values are out of range not able to identify it with excel formula.

Comment: You should edit your question and add all this new info. Also, ¿are all values in same cell or different cells? And if I'm right, then the numeric range is determined always by first and last number of that list of values? Also, you posted data example, but it would be helpful if you post how is data displayed in Excel (your input) and what are you looking in Excel (expected output)

Comment: Attached the input and the expected output of the formula on the second sheet, if continuous values are out of range then it does not show the 'Y" value in the second sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got solved using python SciPy library in Python using interpolation and regression model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).